# How to forbid a user to merge revision from other users

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

We have a subversion repository

- trunk
- q&a branch
- release branch

When Q&A are testing our web site we work on the Q&A branch, commit / update to resolve some bugs.

When we finish debugging we want to put all our fixes in the trunk, so we get the trunk , merge (without filtering on the revision n°) and then commit back to the trunk. 
The problem is : the web designer (who handle xslt and css files) can merge changes on code files (like c#) and when there is conflict he doesn't know what to do (it's the same for me when I have to resolve conflict about xslt files).

The only solution here is to merge  only our revision, but it's prone to error (because there is a manual manipulation).

So I'd like to know if there is a way to tell to the server or to configure the client to merge only revision made by yourself, and  have a super-user who can merge everything.

Comment: ?! if i understand correctly, you would end up merging stuff to the trunk individually which means out of order. That may fail. Can't the web designer only commit those directorys containing html/css? And, how can the web designer commit conflicted files anyway - svn would not allow this without resolving?

Comment: the problem is on the merge not the commit. When he merges everything from the Q&A to the trunk he also merges .cs files so there might be conflict during the merge between the c# files in the Q&A and the c# file in the trunk

Comment: So let the web developer only merge *his* files. You don't have to merge or commit all directoies at once.

Comment: that's my question : they have to select all their revisions (because it's better to merge at the root of the branch), and it's a manual process : going on the log, selecting the revisions ... I'd prefer to avoid it.

Comment: But why is it better to merge at the root of the branch, then? The end result of (a) selecting the revisions which contain the web developers commits and merging/committing them is the same as (b) doing the merge/commit only on those directories which contain "their" files, without the trouble of having to select revisions...

Comment: Because like that we can track the merging with the merge info property at the root of the branch, and we never face the problem when we merge just a part of a revision.